# Como seleccionar todas las celdas de un UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy implementando un UITableViewController con Multi selección, para esto agrego al método viewDidLoad()

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Luego, para selección y deseleccion de celdas los métodos

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("===== Seleccionar \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("===== Deseleccionar \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Finalmente el array de las celdas seleccionadas las obtengo de la siguiente forma desde un botón

```
let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
let selectedData = selectedRows?.map { self.arrDatos[$0.row]}
print("===== array de elementos seleccionados: \(String(describing: selectedData))")
```

Como se puede seleccionar y deseleccionar todas las celdas del TableView para un (Seleccionar todo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llamar dentro de un `for` al método `selectRow` para seleccionar todas las filas y el método `deselectRow` para deseleccionar. Yo lo tengo así:

```
@IBAction func seleccionarTodo(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    for fila in 0..<self.valores.count { //Recorres el for con los valores del array
        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: fila, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none) //Seleccionas la fila
    }

}
```

Para deseleccionar todo sería igual:

```
@IBAction func seleccionarTodo(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    for fila in 0..<self.valores.count { //Recorres el for con los valores del array

        tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath(row: fila, section: 0), animated: true)//Deseleccionas la fila
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, fue útil la respuesta. Saludos.